# NullPointerException when invoking a static method for data input

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

It seems to me that I've done everything right, but the NullPointerException is thrown. I assume it is not about file, cause there would be FileNotFoundExcepion.
The method is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class InputFileData 
{
    public static Product [] readProductDataFile(File inputFile)
                                                             throws IOException
    {
    try
    {
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(inputFile); 

        int range = Integer.parseInt(fileScan.nextLine());
        String codeData = fileScan.nextLine();
        String priceData = fileScan.nextLine();

        Scanner codeDataScan = new Scanner(codeData);
        codeDataScan.useDelimiter("#");

        Scanner priceDataScan = new Scanner(priceData);
        priceDataScan.useDelimiter("#");            

        Product [] productRange = new Product[range];

        for(int i = 0; i < range; i++)
        {
            productRange[i].setProductCode(codeDataScan.next());
            productRange[i].setPricePerUnit(Integer.
                                        parseInt(priceDataScan.nextLine()));
        }

        return productRange;    
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In the main method I use:

```
    try
    {
    File productData = new File("productData.txt");
    Product [] consideredRange = InputFileData.readProductDataFile(productData);

    for(int i = 0; i < consideredRange.length; i++)
        System.out.println(i + "./n" + consideredRange[i]);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

And the data in a file looks like this:

```
10
PA/1234#PV/5732#Au/9271#DT/9489#HY/7195#ZR/7413#bT/4674#LR/4992#Xk/8536#kD/9767#
153#25#172#95#235#159#725#629#112#559#

Line 1 - number of items
Line 2 - Product code
Line 3 - price
```

What is wrong then?

Thank you!

Edit:

```
at Assignment2.InputFileData.readProductDataFile(InputFileData.java:35) at Assignment2.InputFileData.readProductDataFile(InputFileData.java:35)
at Assignment2.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:211)
```

The line 35 is                 productRange[i].setProductCode(codeDataScan.next());

Solution:

productRange[i] = new Product(codeDataScan.next(), Integer.parseInt(priceDataScan.next()));

Comment: Add the stack trace and highlight the line where the error occurs

Comment: You need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels    I've never used debugger unfortunately..  It is definitely something important to get used with.

Comment: Arthur, what I suggested above doesn't require a debugger at all -- just a set of eyeballs.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels, what is exception's stacktrace? The message which is thrown by default?

Comment: The message that tells you that a NPE was thrown -- that's the stacktrace. It tells you the line numbers of the exception and all. You should **always** post this with your question (you didn't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialise the contents of the `productRange` array

```
Product [] productRange = new Product[range];
```

Creates an array capable of `Product` whose elements are all `null`

You then try to "modify" each element...

```
for(int i = 0; i < range; i++)
{
    productRange[i].setProductCode(codeDataScan.next());
    productRange[i].setPricePerUnit(Integer.
                                    parseInt(priceDataScan.nextLine()));
}
```

Which is the probable cause of you NPE

You need to intiailsie the element of the array BEFORE you initialise it

```
for(int i = 0; i < range; i++)
{
    productRange[i] = new Product();
    productRange[i].setProductCode(codeDataScan.next());
    productRange[i].setPricePerUnit(Integer.
                                    parseInt(priceDataScan.nextLine()));
}
```

When diagnosing these types of problems, you can use `System.out.println` (or an appropriate logger) to help you identify problem areas and use the debugger to inspect the state (and flow) of your program.

Comment: MadProgrammer, thank you for explanation! But what if my construtor for a new Product requires the code and price as a parameters?

Comment: you were right about the reason of exception by the way!

Comment: Of course... Here it is: productRange[i] = new Product(codeDataScan.next(), Integer.parseInt(priceDataScan.nextLine()));

Comment: Remember, debug, debug, debug ;)